# Godaddy subdomain issue with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with my htaccess file. I'm placing my site under a subdomain in which the subdomain points to the www folder. The folder structure of the site is:

```
project
----app (controllers, models, etc)
----www (index.php, js, styles)
```

The htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

This works fine locally for development, but not on Godaddy. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: do you have mod rewrite enabled?

Comment: along same lines as Jeff is suggesting... Server versions other configuration differences between the two environments.  Error logs have any hints?

Comment: And if nothing in log consider adding to host declaration: `RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: goDaddy is a terrible host with ridiculous restrictions, flee

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was missing `RewriteBase /`.